# How to get javascript with cucumber?

Tags: javascript, cucumber

I meet some problems when using cucumber.

Here is my arborescence

```
-- app1
    |-- features
    |   |-- addition.feature
    |   |-- step_definitions
    |   `-- support
    |       `-- env.js
    |-- public
    |   `-- javascripts
    |       |-- Player.js
    |       `-- Song.js
    |-- Rakefile
    `-- spec
        `-- javascripts
            |-- helpers
            |   `-- SpecHelper.js
            |-- PlayerSpec.js
            `-- support
                |-- jasmine_config.rb
                |-- jasmine_runner.rb
                `-- jasmine.yml
```

Here is my file "addition.feature"

```
Feature: Addition
  In order to avoid silly mistakes
  As a math idiot
  I want to be told the sum of two numbers

  Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
    And I have entered 70 into the calculator
    When  press add
    Then the result should be 120 on the screen
```

When I run

> cucumber features/addition.feature

I get

```
Feature: Addition
  In order to avoid silly mistakes
  As a math idiot
  I want to be told the sum of two numbers

  Scenario: Add two numbers                     # features/addition.feature:6
    Given I have entered 50 into the calculator # features/addition.feature:7
    And I have entered 70 into the calculator   # features/addition.feature:8
    When press add                              # features/addition.feature:9
    Then the result should be 120 on the screen # features/addition.feature:10

1 scenario (1 undefined)
4 steps (4 undefined)
0m0.003s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given /^I have entered (\d+) into the calculator$/ do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

When /^press add$/ do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Then /^the result should be (\d+) on the screen$/ do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

If you want snippets in a different programming language, just make sure a file
with the appropriate file extension exists where cucumber looks for step definitions.
```

Why is the output in ruby language, am I not supposed to get javascript, considering I have a ".js" file in "support/" directory?

Comment: I've found the solution, the gem "therubyracer" was missing. 
Thanks Michael Koper anyway

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

> gem install therubyracer

found on http://css.dzone.com/articles/writing-cucumber-step

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can use capybara to test javascript. A quick search on google: http://openmonkey.com/2010/04/09/javascript-testing-with-cucumber-capybara/

Comment: Thanks, but a friend of mine is doing the same procedure (we have the same ruby version, the same cucumber version), and getting an output in js.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Cucumber.js](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js). It is the official port of Cucumber to JavaScript.

Keep in mind that it's still missing several features compared to cucumber-ruby (background, tables, tags, etc.).

The scenario you're exposing here should run just fine against cucumber.js, though.

Answer (score -1):

You can install CukeTest if you are using Windows 10. Just search CukeTest in Windows Store, it provides visual way to edit gherkin file and generate JavaScript functions automatically.

Comment: OP had a specific problem and found a solution to it. Offering a program that can do something similar is not helping.